# Sort order of selected items in ListView with CheckedTextView

Tags: android, listview, sorting, checkedtextview

I successfully implemented an `AlertDialog` that shows a `custom-styled-row` of `CheckedTextViews`. The problem comes when selecting the items. At the end, the order is going to be established by their position in the `ListView`. If a user selects an item from the bottom of the list and then an item from the top, the answer given by the `Dialog's` `OnClickListener` will begin with the top one instead from the bottom one. Is there a way to sort these items by click?

Here is my implementation to retrieve the items checked:

```
private void setCheckedItems(){

    SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
    if (checkedItems != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i<checkedItems.size(); i++) {
            if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
                mSelectedItems.add(tables[checkedItems.keyAt(i)]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I tried to avoid this problem by calling `OnItemClickListener` on my `ListView`, but the items that were in positions longer than the space of the screen began to be checked as well. So, at the end I used `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);` instead of the click listener.

Thank you very much.

Comment: cant you on every check box selection, add the value or position into an arraylist? instead of doing it all at the end?

Comment: How? 'OnItemClickListener' is not doing it for me :/

Comment: you hve the listview? set the onItemClickListener as listview.setOnItemClickListener(this); and implement the method, once done, in the onItemClick method, check the state of the checkbox and check it or uncheck it, and if checked add it to the list if its not in the list. on uncheck, remove it from the list.